# Scheduled task that runs a MS Access Macro without any user logged in on the server? Is it Possible?

Tags: excel, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run an scheduled task that runs a MS Access Macro without any user logged in on the server. So far I've tried with:

Batch file:   `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Contacts.accdb" /x MyMacro`

.VBS file:

```
Option Explicit
dim oaccess
set oaccess = createobject("access.application")
oaccess.opencurrentdatabase("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Contacts.accdb")
oaccess.docmd.runmacro "MyMacro"
oaccess.closecurrentdatabase
oaccess.quit
set oaccess=nothing
WScript.Quit(0)
```

Batch that calls .VBS file:

```
wscript //nologo //B C:\macro.vbs
```

All the methods above run the Macro successfully as long as the User in the "Run As" property of the Scheduled Task is logged in. If I run the same task but with a user account that is not logged in the task stays on "Running State" and it creates a new MSACCESS.EXE process every time the scheduled task is called.
I've tried creating a new user with Admin privileges and "Log on as a batch job" and "Log on as a service" permissions in gpedit.msc, Also with NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account but had no luck.

After several hours of being searching for a solution I found this:
Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Is it even possible to run a Scheduled Task (that executes a MSAccess Macro) without any user logged in or MS Access need to have the Scheduled Task user connected in order to run the Macro ? IF it's truly not possible, is there a workaround to solve the equivalent problem, or must a 3rd party software that can do this be purchased?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: At least, run it from a folder not owned by a specific user. But even you succeed, the documentation is correct; many attempts have been done, but Access is a user/desktop application, not a service, so it won't run reliably.

Comment: So what would you recommend? Is there seriously no workaround that can accomplish this problem? Why would task scheduler even invent a "Run without logged on" checkbox if it were impossible to do these kind of things through a batch file. Makes no sense.

Comment: You could set up autologon on the (virtual) machine using a specific non-admin account to run the application in a logged-on session. I would program a service in .Net (C# or VB.NET). Of course, if you create reports, it may not be that simple as the report writer in Visual Studio is very different from that of Access.